# ULogin + Yii Rights. Проблема с гостем

Tags: yii, авторизация, права, ulogin

Начал работать с Yii и делаю сайт. В качестве авторизации использую uLogin. Права реализую расширением rights.

Практически смог их объединить, проблема в следующем.
Если пользователь залогинен и он админ или обычный пользователь, то все нормально. Функция Rights::getAssignedRoles() выдает нужные значения Admin или Authenticated.

Но если пользователь просто гость и просматривает страницу, то эта функция выдает ему сразу 3 роли Admin, Authenticated, Guest и доступ работает неправильно. Если я принудительно установлю какому-нибудь зарегистрированному пользователю роль Guest, то тоже все работает правильно.

Где искать косяк? Вроде проверил все уже несколько раз.

Comment: ох, где-то скручивал их + yii-user и даже припоминается эта проблема, но вот где этот проект. попробую откопать и заодно поржать какой-же костыль я там сделал.  
А нет, пардон. Связывал с eauth.

Comment: а причем тут ulogin?

Comment: В смысле причем? Я его использую в проекте и связываю с rights